# SWRevealViewController swipe gesture causes app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, swrevealviewcontroller

I have an app that implements SWRevealViewController and I am having a few issues with it.

I have two issues which I am guessing are probably related to each other (I am not sure as I am quite new to this).

If I am on a view controller that has been presented from the SWRevealController class and I go to another view controller via a present modally segue and then back to the previous view controller also via a present modally segue then the app crashes, this only happens on view controllers that implement the swipe gesture recogniser for the SWRevealController class, so for all view controllers where this occurs for the moment I have commented out the gesture recogniser and have added a bar button item into the nav bar and made that present the menu via the SWRevealController class. All the code I use for the SWRevealController functionality is from the SWRevealController tutorial on AppCoda which I followed while implementing the class (http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/).

This is it (correct class file for SWRevealViewController is also imported):

```
barButton.target = self.revealViewController;
barButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

The bar button item shows no error when it is tapped, it just doesn't do anything. If the view controller has the gesture recogniser then the app crashes with this error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

---

None of the code I have written on the view controller that this happened on has any array's on it so I can't see how it could be a problem with my code but as I said earlier I am quite new to this so I am not sure.

Both the swipe gesture and the bar button item work if I don't go to another view controller and then back again.

Comment: If you are on a VC that was presented modally, you do not go "back to the previous view controller also via a present modally segue." You dismiss the current modal.

Comment: Ah okay, how do I do that? There is no option for dismissing anything when I try and create a segue in the storyboard.

Comment: I have figured it out. Thank you very much. If you put your comment as an answer then I can mark what you said as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely stemming from the statement in your question:

> ...I go to another view controller via a present modally segue and then back to the previous view controller also via a present modally segue...

You don't go back to previous controllers by presenting modally, rather you need to *dismiss* your current modal.